# Модульное тестирование: работа с файлами

Tags: тестирование, юнит-тесты

Как лучше всего тестировать работу с файлами? Например, я пишу тесты для класса работы с конфигами (чтение/запись).

У него есть конструктор, в которое передается имя файла и методы get (получить значение параметра из конфиг. файла), set (установить  значение параметра для конфиг. файла) и commit(применить изменения). Как сделать тестирование get и set - ясно. Но как (и надо ли) сделать работу с файлами при создании объекта и при сохранении?

PS. Также, хотелось бы увидеть наиболее интересные, с Вашей точки зрения, книги по модульному тестированию (желательно, именно с такой теоретической информацией, без привязки к языку; ну или применительно к java/php).

Книжку нашел [вот такую](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1501671/). Вроде бы довольно интересная.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам недавно столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Правда в связке .net+sqlite+nunit если интересно будет вот ссылка на статью [Test a DataReader](http://www.csharptocsharp.com/unit-test-datareader-with-mocks-and-stubs).

Comment: Да, примерно разобрался в какую сторону копать, ковыряю сейчас мок-объекты, в принципе, как делать уже ясно.

Comment: Удачи тебе)